# How do you send in multiple commands to Sql PowerShell from the Windows Command Line?

Tags: sql-server-2008, scripting, powershell, ssms

Not sure if this belongs on serverfault or not...

I am following the instructions on [this](http://sev17.com/2008/12/registering-sql-servers-in-2000-em-2005-ssms-and-2008-ssms/) site for adding registered servers to sql studio management studio via powershell. It works great one at a time, but I need to do it for 60 servers.

I have a batch set up with the code for each create that I need. I can't get the syntax right for calling sqlps by the command line and passing in the whole series of commands.
My batch is set up like so:

```
sqlps -NoExit -Command { cd 'SQLSERVER:\sqlregistration\Database Engine Server Group\' new-item $(Encode-Sqlname server1) -itemtype registration -Value "server=server1;integrated security=true" ... and so on }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Chad pointing me in the right direction, I came up with this, which worked:

A batch file with multiple lines, each line looking like this:

```
sqlps -Command "&{ cd 'SQLSERVER:\sqlregistration\Database Engine Server Group'; new-item $(Encode-Sqlname serverX) -itemtype registration -Value \"server=serverX;integrated security=true\";}"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have each individual new-item listed on a separate line in a PS1 file, for example assuming I have a file named register.ps1 with the following lines.:

```
cd 'SQLSERVER:\sqlregistration\Database Engine Server Group\'; new-item $(Encode-Sqlname server1) -itemtype registration -Value "server=server1;integrated security=true" 
cd 'SQLSERVER:\sqlregistration\Database Engine Server Group\'; new-item $(Encode-Sqlname server2) -itemtype registration -Value "server=server1;integrated security=true"
```

You could call sqlps like this:

```
sqlps -NoExit -Command "&{C:\bin\register.ps1}"
```

A better solution would be to add parameters to the register.ps1

```
param($ServerInstance)

cd 'SQLSERVER:\sqlregistration\Database Engine Server Group\'
New-Item $(Encode-Sqlname $server) -itemtype registration -Value "server=$serverInstance;integrated security=true"
```

Then then create a file with the list of SQL Instances, for example server.txt:

```
server1
server2
```

Call register.ps1 for each line:

```
get-content C:\bin\server.txt | foreach {C:\bin\register.ps1 $_ }
```

Comment: I tried this, and I would see the lines of code shoot by, but they wouldn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Put semi-colons between the commands.

Comment: No luck...Even running sqlps -NoExit -Command { cd 'SQLSERVER:\sqlregistration\Database Engine Server Group\Stores'; }
 leaves me at the prompt "PS SQLSERVER:\>" so the directory isn't even changing...

Comment: Are you running this from PowerShell, or something else?  (Like cmd.exe)